# Space between navbar and carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a solution to remove the ugly space around the carousel? I want the carousel to fill the screen out and be right under the navbar. I have linked an image below.

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  margin-bottom: 0;
```

}

the code above does not work with carousels!

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">McNiels <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
              <li><a href="news.html">News<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span> </a></li>
              <li><a href="music.html">Music <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="david guetta.jpg" alt="David Guetta">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="zedd.jpg" alt="Zedd">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="steve aoki.jpg" alt="Steve Aoki">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="hardwell.jpg" alt="Hardwell">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>


<img id="avicii" src="avicii2.jpg" alt="" />
<img id="martin" src="martin garrix.jpg" alt="" />
<img id="david" src="david guetta2.jpg" alt="" />
<img id="zedd" src="zedd2.jpg" alt="" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmRGq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extra `</li>` and `</div>`
This will help

Answer (score 1):

Don't place a break `<br>` before the carousel (and maybe not inside a container if you want it to be full-width). Other then those, `margin-bottom: 0;`.

Sidenote: You have extra `li` and `ul` tags in your navbar.

Working Example Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">McNiels <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span> </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="music.html">Music <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2500x750/f00" alt="David Guetta">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2500x750/000" alt="Zedd">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2500x750/ff0" alt="Steve Aoki">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2500x750/444" alt="Hardwell">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>



<img id="avicii" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/2500x750/666" alt="" />
<img id="martin" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/2500x750/444" alt="" />
<img id="david" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/2500x750/000" alt="" />
<img id="zedd" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/2500x750/f00" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this,

```
  .navbar.navbar-inverse {
     margin-bottom: -20px;
    }
```

You can find a demo [here](http://www.bootply.com/UTubaCfrUO).

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove/add tags (li and div) this effect space
```